# Print the result of the operations on Python

Tags: python

I need to print the result of each Num to make a face. By putting three pairs of numbers, each one will give you a symbol, and in the end I need to print together all the symbols received before.

```
Num1 = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))

if Num1 % 6 == 0:
    print (":")
elif Num1 % 2 == 0:
    print("X")
elif Num1 % 3 == 0:
    print("8")
elif Num1 % 4 == 0:
    print ("=")
elif Num1 % 5 == 0:
    print("[")
elif Num1 % 1== 0:
    print(";")

Num2 = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))

if Num2 % 4 == 0:
    print ("-")
elif Num2 % 2 == 0:
    print("-{")
elif Num2 % 3 == 0:
    print("<{")
elif Num2 % 1== 0:
    print("<")

Num3 = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))

if Num3 % 7 == 0:
    print ('(')
elif Num3 % 2 == 0:
    print("O")
elif Num3 % 3 == 0:
    print("|")
elif Num3 % 4== 0:
    print("!")
elif Num3 % 5 == 0:
    print("/")
elif Num3 % 6 == 0:
    print("P")
elif Num3 % 1== 0:
    print(")")
```

I tried this, but it will only print the numbers that were input before, and not the symbols. What can I do?

```
print(Num1, Num2, Num3)
```

Comment: Naive approach? Assign to another variable rather than `print`ing within your `if` statements. A better way would be to map input and expected output to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` as the name suggests prints something onto the console.
As you want to create a face, you should instead of `print` store the face parts in a variable.

Going by your code here is a shorter example:

```py
face = ""
num = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))

# IF num is divisible by 6
if num % 6 == 0:
    # THEN concatenate ":" at the end of the string
    face += ":"
# ELSE IF num is divisible by 2
elif num % 2 == 0:
    # THEN concatenate "X" at the end of the string
    face += "X"

# GET next number
num = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))
# Concatenate next string part to face
if num % 4 == 0:
    face += "-"
elif num % 2 == 0:
    face += "-{"

# Get last number
num = int(input("Tell me a whole number: "))
if num % 7 == 0:
    face += '('
elif num % 2 == 0:
    face += "O"

print(face)
```

This will give you the following output when entering the numbers `6`, `4` and `7`:

```py
:-(
```